# How to access all key value of dictionary with specific format

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary. I want to show the dictionary as like as how python get value from dictionary.
For clarification an example shown below:

```
example = {"a": 1, "b": "2", "c": 3, "d": {"x": "b", "y": "p", "q": {"w": 1, "z": "2"}}}
value_dict = {}

def recursive_items(dictionary):
    for key in dictionary:
        sub_data = dictionary[key]
        if isinstance(sub_data, dict):
            new_dict = {}
            for sub_key in sub_data:
                # new_dict[f"{key}.{sub_key}"]=sub_data[sub_key]
                new_dict[f"{key}.{sub_key}"] = f"data.get('{key}').get('{sub_key}')"
                recursive_items(new_dict)
        else:
            value_dict[key]=dictionary[key]
    return value_dict

items=recursive_items(example)
print(items)
```

The current output is :

```
{'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3, 'd.x': "data.get('d').get('x')", 'd.y': "data.get('d').get('y')", 'd.q': "data.get('d').get('q')"}
```

But I want the output like below:

```
{'a': "data.get('a')", 'b': "data.get('b')", 'c': "data.get('c')", 'd.x': "data.get('d').get('x')", 'd.y': "data.get('d').get('y')", 'd.q.w': "data.get('d').get('q').get('w'),'d.q.z': "data.get('d').get('q').get('z')"}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not recursing the dictionary, moreover, in the else part you did not set the path of the key like:

```
value_dict[key]= f"data.get('{key}')"
```

Actually, in these types of problems, I would recommend you to divide the problem into several parts and then conquer them. For instance, in this problem, there were two cases

1. One case when the sub_data is a dictionary
2. One case when the sub_data is of another type
   Therefore, one possible solution was to recurse the dictionary until you reach the non-dictionary type value and then write the path and desired string in a new dictionary like:

```
    value_dict[key_str]= path_str
```

where key_str is the path to that key and path_str is the value in format f"data.get()" etc. I have configured the following solution for this. You may modify or optimize the code yourself.

```
example = {"a": 1, "b": "2", "c": 3, "d": {"x": "b", "y": "p", "q": {"w": 1, "z": "2"}}}
value_dict = {}
def recursive_items(dictionary,path=None):
    for key in dictionary:
        sub_data = dictionary[key]
        if isinstance(sub_data, dict):
            if path is None:
                recursive_items(sub_data,f"{key}")
            else:
                recursive_items(sub_data,f"{path}.{key}")
        else:
            path_str = "data"
            key_str = key
            if not path is None:
                key_str = f"{path}.{key}"
                path_keys = path.split('.')
                for p_key in path_keys:
                    path_str = f"{path_str}.get('{p_key}')"
            path_str = f"{path_str}.get('{key}')"
            value_dict[key_str]= path_str
    return value_dict

items=recursive_items(example)
print(items)
```

The output of this code is

> {'a': "data.get('a')", 'b': "data.get('b')", 'c': "data.get('c')", 'd.x': "data.get('d').get('x')", 'd.y': "data.get('d').get('y')", 'd.q.w': "data.get('d').get('q').get('w')", 'd.q.z': "data.get('d').get('q').get('z')"}

Comment: The pleasure is mine.